# Chrome hanging for 5-10 seconds regularly

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am having issues with Chrome hanging fairly regularly. I am using Version 33.0.1750.154 m, updated this morning.

Basically, what happens is shortly after loading a page, it's like the entire browser just exists the timeline for a few seconds. The page stops responding. I can't click to a new tab. Even the spinny-wheel indicating that the page is loading stops spinning. After between 5 and 10 seconds, everything comes back, and all actions I had done during that time appear to be cached. So, if I clicked a tab during the frozen period, then it will switch to that tab. If I closed a tab, that tab would then close, etc.

I've disable plugins and extensions. I've periodically disabled web protection in my AV programs. I've monitored CPU and memory usage and nothing seems awry.

Typically, when this happens, the browser says "Waiting for xxx..." at the bottom status bar, where "xxx" represents the site I'm trying to visit.

It also seems to happen when a site in another tab does an auto-refresh. For instance, if I have a twitter feed open in another tab, the problem seems to be correlated with that tab doing an auto-refresh.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: I have looked at the other answers on this site regarding Chrome halting periodically. Those solutions did not fix my problem.

Comment: Can you try and delete your profile data (or move it elsewhere) and then start with blank Chrome to see if that happens? How to create new Default profile is explained here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en

Comment: @D.Kasipovic I just tried that, and on the first webpage I visited, I immediately had issues. However, I did notice that Kaspersky managed to add several extensions to the browser. I removed them, but I suspect it might be the cause nonetheless.